# Disable third party intent receiver menu options in android

Tags: android, android-intent

Is there a way to disable the menu options of a third party intent receiver say a PDF viewer .  If I open a pdf file via the third party option - on clicking the menu button it shows the menu of the third party tool which I dont want. Is there a way to disable it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, you want to disable that a specific app is responding when you try to open a file of a certain filetype. I am not aware of a programming approach, but you could use another 3rd Party app for that purpose. Try "Default App Manager" or "Ghost Commander", if nothing is helping consider deleting the other app if you do not need it.
I hope that helps

Edit:

Integrate the source for opening specific files into your own app, then you can use the menu of your own app ;)

Use these for pdf: 
sourceforge.net/projects/andpdf/develop 
or 
apv.googlecode.com

Comment: Not exactly. Suppose I have to open a pdf file through my application. When I open it, it uses a 3rd party intent viewer like Adobe to open.  But when I click on the menu hardware button - it opens the menu of the pdf viewer. I want to disable this menu for being opened

Comment: ok, it means it is your intent to open the file in the 3rd Party app. So that it is shown inside that App's Activity, but when clicking on the menu Button you expect that the menu of your app is showing up. Well as far as I understand, the only way to get this done is by opening the file in your Activity! So maybe you find a 3rd Party source for opening these files within your Activity. http://sourceforge.net/projects/andpdf/develop or http://apv.googlecode.com/           Good Luck